# Select multiple fields on different rows with ONE query

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

With one MYSQL query only, how can I check if a buyer and a seller have both bought from each other ?

Table : purchase

```
purchase_id     |   seller       |   buyer
       12       |      2         |     5
       29       |      5         |     2
```

If the query returns a result (which would be the case here), then a specific div would appear on the page.

Comment: do you need to enter the id or do you want to find all ID that bought from each other?

Comment: no need to enter the ID. All I need to know is if the query returns a result or not.

Comment: what output do you want to get

Comment: 1 or 0 . The query will be embedded in a if/else statement. If two users have bought from each other, a little handshake symbol will be displayed when they visit each other profile page. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: is this what you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47159/3 but i think you need to enter some ID

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes, this is exactly the logic I was looking for. How can I check a.seller and b.buyer against $id and $uid ? ($id = seller and $uid=buyer).  Can I add another WHERE clause? Feel free to add an answer , i'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) >= 2) AS Result
FROM   purchase a
       INNER JOIN purchase b
         ON a.seller = b.buyer AND
            a.buyer = b.seller
WHERE  (a.seller = 2 AND a.buyer = 5) OR
       (a.seller = 5 AND a.buyer = 2)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47159/4)

just replace `2` and `5` with your variables.